# Enum class comparison other than default

Tags: c++, class, enums

I have the following enum class:

```
enum class MyEnum : int32_t
{
    ENUM1 = EXTERNAL_CONSTANT1,
    ENUM2 = EXTERNAL_CONSTANT2,
    ENUM3 = EXTERNAL_CONSTANT3
};
```

The "EXTERNAL_CONSTANTX" are constant provided from elsewhere (which are more or less special code numbers).

What I want to do is to have an option to compare the enums by priority, which is specified in another document, for example ENUM3 has highest priority, ENUM2 has the lowest (it's totally not correlated with the values of the EXTERNAL_CONSTANT). As far as I checked, C++ doesn't allow to get the index of a particular enum so I could order them in the way their priorities should be applied. My approach is to use a vector of enums, in which all of those are in particular priority order, but I think it's not the best extensible approach.

Is there any better approach to the problem I described? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add your `vector` example code (and how you use them)?

Comment: Just a thought. How about use a `map` to map enum to their priority?

Comment: Everything in the question is accurate, you do have to do this the clumsy way.  You no longer have to uppercase the enum members to make them distinct, that's something :)

Comment: How are the external constants provided? If it's a list in a text file, you could easily create your own pre-compiler for them to produce `.cpp` and `.h` files with everything filled in.

Comment: Two ideas: just encode the priority into the enum itself: `ENUM1=ENUM1_PRIO<<16|EXTERNAL_CONSTANT1`. Or use consecutive numbers for enum, and use two tables (one for external constant, and one for priority). These are the most performant solutions. Of course, you can use `std::(unordered)_map`, but it is not efficient.

Comment: @siv123 Can you initialize the priorities of each element of `MyEnum` at compile-time ? If so, I think @geza 's encoding method would be most efficient. If not so, map is a simple solution.